# Getting error -Djava.ext is not supported. Use -classpath instead

Tags: java, appium, android-sdk-tools, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I am using java 8 and trying to run uiautomatorviewer.bat of Appium tool but I'm getting below error.

```
Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

The bat file consist of below line

```
:SetPath
set javaextdirs=%swt_path%;%frameworkdir%

call "%java_exe%" "-Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs%" "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=%prog_dir%" -jar %jarpath% %*
```

Can someone help me with this error.

I have tried passing the classpath with -cp from command line but it is not working.

Comment: Please post the values of `echo "swt_path=%swt_path%" echo "frameworkdir=%frameworkdir%"`. You can place those as lines after the `set` command